# Hide Yii2 GridView Action buttons

Tags: yii2

I want to hide Yii2 GridView Action Column buttons on the base of model field status.
If status is = 1 then hide view button only.
How I can?

Code:

```
     [  
        'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
        'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width:260px;'],
        'header'=>'Actions',
        'template' => '{view} {delete}',
        'buttons' => [

            //view button
            'view' => function ($url, $model) {
                return Html::a('<span class="fa fa-search"></span>View', $url, [
                            'title' => Yii::t('app', 'View'),
                            'class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-xs',                                  
                ]);
            },
        ],

        'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
            if ($action === 'view') {
                $url ='/jobs/view?id='.$model->jobid;
                return $url;
        }

       ],
```

Comment: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/5c79ab202cce74048957dce586d7ef2796908138/framework/grid/ActionColumn.php#L70 just add  `return $model->status == 1 ? Html::a('<span class="fa fa-search"></span>View', $url, [
                            'title' => Yii::t('app', 'View'),
                            'class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-xs',                                  
                ]) : '';`

Comment: your code worked for me,thanks

Comment: Can you change your comment as answer below?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Read](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/5c79ab202cce74048957dce586d7ef2796908138/framework/grid/ActionColumn.php#L70)

Just add

```php
return $model->status == 1 
    ? Html::a('<span class="fa fa-search"></span>View', $url, [ 
        'title' => Yii::t('app', 'View'),
        'class' =>'btn btn-primary btn-xs', 
      ]) 
    : '';
```

Answer (score 34):

You can use 
    `['class' => ActionColumn::className(),'template'=>'{view} {update}' ]` 
on your gridview.

Answer (score 23):

Use `visibleButtons` property from `ActionColumn` class:

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
    'visibleButtons' => [
        'view' => function ($model, $key, $index) {
            return $model->status !== 1;
         }
    ]
]
```

Reference: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-grid-actioncolumn#$visibleButtons-detail

Answer (score 11):

It can be done like this

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
    'contentOptions' => [],
    'header'=>'Actions',
    'template' => '{view} {update} {delete}',
    'visibleButtons'=>[
        'view'=> function($model){
              return $model->status!=1;
         },
    ]
],
```

Comment: Did not know about the visibleButtons array - nice and clean. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Out of all the answers here, it helped me the most!

Answer (score 7):

In yii2 use `return Url::to(['controler/action']);`

altogether

```
        [
        'class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn',
        'template' => '{today_action}',
        'buttons' => [
                        'today_action' => function ($url, $model) {
                        return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>', $url, 
                        [
                            'title' => Yii::t('app', 'Change today\'s lists'),
                        ]);
                    }
                ],
                'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
            if ($action === 'today_action') {
                return Url::to(['customers/today']);
            }
        }
            ],
```

I am using kartik extension but works fine with yii

Answer (score 3):

you need to add the template propiety ('template'=>'{update} {delete}') to the column arry where you put the options

```
    'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'id', 
            'otherfield'
['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn','template'=>'{update} {delete}'],
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have done https://github.com/Mihai-P/yii2theme-brain/blob/master/widgets/ActionColumn.php in short I have extended the ActionColumn class and use my own instead of the default one.
my class has more things in it, like checking for access privileges and showing only the buttons they have access to, you can ignore that part and just use the way to check for the way to check for the model. I consider this more reusable then writing code in the view. If you start writing code in the view then you have to write the same code over and over again for each screen.

I am sure you can also do what you want inside the view, try using

```
'template' => function ($model) {
            .............
        }
```

And return either '{view} {delete}' or '{delete}'

Answer (score 1):

You need to change one line only.

**Replace:**

```html
'template' => '{update} {delete}',
```

**With:**

```html
'template' => function($model){
   return ($model->status==1)?'{update} {delete}':'{view} {update} {delete}';
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Its works for me:

```
         'buttons' => [
            'view' => function ($url, $model) {
                return $model->status == '' ? Html::a('<span class="fa fa-paperclip fa-fw fa-border"></span>', $url, [
                            'title' => Yii::t('app', 'Visualizar'),
                            //'class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-xs',                                  
                ]) : '';
            },
```

is the same as: return $model->status == '' ? 'show_action_here' : 'no_show';

Comment: yes...is the same as: return $model->status == '' ? 'yes' : 'no';

Answer (score 0):

this one worked for me . complete ActionColumn code

```
[  
                'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width:260px;'],
                'header'=>'Actions',
                'template' => '{view}',
                'buttons' => [

                    //view button
                    'view' => function ($url, $model) {
                        return  Html::a('<span class="fa fa-search"></span>View', $url, 
[ 'title' => Yii::t('app', 'View'), 'class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-xs', ]) ;
                    },
                ],

                'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
                    if ($action === 'view') {
                        $url = \yii\helpers\Url::toRoute(['general-info/viewalldetails', 'id' => $key]);
                        return $url;
                }
                }
],
```