# How to add a button in the column action, row filter inside the GridView Yii framework 2

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

How do I add a button in the column action, row filter inside the GridView Yii framework 2. I know how to customize or add button in any row and any column, except the cell of the action column and the filter row of GridView.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27142206/hide-yii2-gridview-action-buttons

Comment: you can extend GridView and override `renderTableHeader` or `renderFilters` methods

Answer (score 0):

Add custom button in action column.

```
      [
        'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
        'template' => '{my_action}',
        'buttons' => [
                        'my_action' => function ($url, $model) {
                        return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>', $url, 
                        [
                            'title' => Yii::t('app', 'My Action'),
                        ]);
                    }
                ],
        'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
            if ($action === 'my_action') {
                return Url::to(['user/my-action']);
            }
        }
     ],
```

Comment: not just inside the action column but in the filter row as well. Thank you!